# Error while unmarshal an XML with JAXB caused by DTD file

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, dtd, unmarshalling

I try to unmarhshal a file XML file (`test.xml`) with JAXB (`javax.xml.bind.JAXB`) but it gives me this error:

> [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId:
> file:/C:/Users/EXAMPLE/AppData/Local/Eclipse/workspace_4.4.0/EXAMPLE/test.xml;
> lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 42; Externe DTD: Lesen von externer DTD
> "example.dtd" nicht erfolgreich, da "file"-Zugriff wegen der von der
> Eigenschaft "accessExternalDTD" festgelegten Einschränkung nicht
> zulässig ist.]

English Translation:

> Reading from external DTD "example.dtd"  not succesful , cause
> "File"-Access is not allowed by the Restriction set by the Properties
> "accessExternalDTD"

Solutions already tried:

- Checked if all users including system has access to R/W both files.
- Deleted and used new files to test.
- Tried To find this `accessExternalDTD` properties.

Stuff to notice:

- Project is running in Subversion
- I used the same method on previous projects and the same `.dtd` and `.xml` file and it worked well
- Content of the LINE 2 From the XML File: `<!DOCTYPE EXAMPLE SYSTEM "example.dtd">`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `accessExternalDTD` property can be controlled with the system property `javax.xml.accessExternalDTD`, so start your program with `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=true` and it should work. It should also be possible to set the property on the unmarshaller, try this:

```
unmarshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Comment: Thank you allot ! i will try it ASAP so i can accept your answer if its working :)

Comment: "-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=true" does not work, "-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all" does! A bit more portable would be to do this in code:
System.setProperty("javax.xml.accessExternalDTD", "all");
The unmarshaller.setProperty() solution did not work for me.

Comment: @HammerNL You are my saver! This might deserve its own thread or as another answer.

Comment: This answer does not explain what accessExternalDTD=all does, or whether doing this is safe.

Answer (score 6):

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("input.xml"));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
    }

}
```

Comment: This solves the exception indeed, but note that this DISABLES DTD checking, which might not be what you want!

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically:

```
System.setProperty(
    "javax.xml.accessExternalDTD", "file" );
```

or at startup include 
 `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all`

Either way resolved it for me. 
The value can be "file" or "all" or a comma-separated list.
I tried the accepted answer but in my case setting the property on the **unmarshaller** caused a **javax.xml.bind.PropertyException** 
*More details of my environment:*
I'm using the

- **Microsoft OpenJDK 11 on Windows**
  added the jars for JaxB 2.x
- **Migrated from OpenJDK 8 from RH**